# How to prevent play store from detecting VPN?

Tags: google-play-store, vpn

I live in China so in order for me access play store I must use a VPN. Play store however, has disabled me from accessing and downloading updates via VPN.

I can activate (after each time I upgrade the system) play store by not being in China or setting up a VPN on a router and then connect my phone to the router. Either way is a bit annoying.

Then when I need to download updates or a new app, I must first navigate to a specific page, tap update or install, and then switch off the VPN for play store to start downloading and then quickly switch on the VPN before the download fails. This is quite annoying too.

Is there a way via some root trick that I can just disable play store from knowing I am using a VPN?

I am on Android-10 and play store 18, some older devices don't have this problem, btw.

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem. Also those links u posted r just VPN apps.

Comment: just recommended from german forum with same problem (playstore not downloading over VPN)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most successful methods I use (which you can also use in this case) to bypass VPN detection is using an anonymous or elite proxy.

To implement the proxy on a per-app basis you can use [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&utm_source=android.downloadatoz.com) or any similar application.

After connecting the VPN simply grab an elite/anonymous proxy from paid or free sites like this one: [hidemy.name](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/).

Open ProxyDroid and input the elite proxy and filter to use with Google Play (or other apps if desired).

Connect and download.